# Uncaught Error: Exception in makeTransliteratable: Invalid element id lang

Tags: javascript

I am using the following js code to convert local language from English in a django app.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

```
// Load the Google Transliteration API
google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "transliteration"
});

function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage: 'en',
        destinationLanguage: ['ml'],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };
    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required options.

    var control =  new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.    
    var ids = [ "lang", "langu", "language" ];
    control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

    // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
    // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
    // control.showControl('translControl');
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

The error on console is

```
 Uncaught Error: Exception in makeTransliteratable: Invalid element id lang
    at Yy (transliteration.I.js:178)
    at Xy.Q.ij (transliteration.I.js:323)
    at onLoad ((index):551)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `var ids = [ "lang", "langu", "language" ];` the `lang` in this piece of code seems to be invalid

Comment: whatever I put there or even a single id, it gives the same error, site link is http://cjquora-dev3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Comment: where is the documentation for the package that you are using?

Comment: A little googling and I came across this - https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started - is this it and if so its been deprecated since 2011. Have you read these docs? Is your list  of ids a list of `html` elements? Your code doesnt look like the code in the documentation. Maybe read the docs first?